# useEffect navigate to screen when condition met

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

In useEffect, how can I check each array item has the same vrn and a completed date, so I can navigate them to a different screen:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const isComplete = (completedOn) => completedOn !== '';

    if (maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.every(isComplete)) {
      navigation.navigate(AppRoutes.MaintenanceIntroVehicleSuccess.Name);
    }
  }, []);
```

completed state:

```
[
    {
        "id": "Tyres",
        "vrn": "WU71JWE",
        "completedOn": "2023-10-31T10:20:25.217Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "Wipers and Screenwash",
        "vrn": "WU71JWE",
        "completedOn": "2023-10-31T10:20:54.743Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "Exterior lights",
        "vrn": "WU71JWE",
        "completedOn": "2023-10-31T10:21:27.140Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something in the dependency array to check when the `maintenanceReminder` has changed.

Some people say that `maintenanceReminder` is sufficient but you would get many re-runs from the `useEffect` if `maintenanceReminder` is simply a defined variable

i.e. not coming from state:

```js
const [maintenanceReminder, setMaintenanceReminder] = useState([]);
```

if `maintenanceReminder.checkHistory` is simply being created from a variable, then `JSON.stringify(maintenanceReminder.checkHistory)` may be sufficient because checking a `string` will result in fewer rerunsby the `useEffect` becuase a "complex" (JSON or Array) object will cause the `useEffect` to run many more times that you would want because of the way React checks the dependencies [Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#removing-unnecessary-object-dependencies)

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if (maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.length === 3 && SOME_OTHER_CHECK) {
      navigation.navigate(AppRoutes.MaintenanceIntroVehicleSuccess.Name);
    }

  }, [JSON.stringify(maintenanceReminder)]);
```

I've included `SOME_OTHER_CHECK` because you mention that you want to check that the `"vrn"` is all the same and there is a completed date.

##### VRN Check

You could check that all the VRN are the same for every item in the array

```js
const firstVRN = maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.length > 0
  ? maintenanceReminder.checkHistory[0].vrn
  : "";

maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.every(item =>
  item.vrn === firstVRN
);
```

##### Complettion date check

I'd need to more information about the types of possible values for completion date.
But you could do something similar that checks that every date is valid.

```js
const isDateValid(dateStr) {
  return !isNaN(new Date(dateStr));
}

...

maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.every(item =>
  isDateValid(checkDateIsValitem.completedOn)
);
```

NOTE: I assumed that `maintenanceReminder.checkHistory.length === 3` is just a temporary check at the moment as you want to check the VRN and completed dates